# Eclipse format or clean up changed files

Tags: eclipse, code-formatting

In Intellij Idea I can open `Local Changes tab` select files and invoke formatting code. How i can do this in Eclipse?

How can I format and clean up ONLY changed files in Eclipse?

I can get list of changed files on "Git Staging" view, but select files on this view don't allow me to invoke Source/Clean Up... or Source/Format operation.

Comment: I use Source -> Cleanup Document... At least it works and only when I want it to!!

Answer (score 1):

1. Select all in `Git Staging view`
2. Right-click on the files
3. Click on `Show in` > `Package explorer`
   [image: <code>Show in</code> > <code>Package explorer</code>]
4. Right-click on the selected files in the Package explorer
5. Click on `Source` > `Clean Up...` ou `Format`
   [image: <code>Source</code> > <code>Clean Up...</code>]

PS: you can do this for former commits:

1. Show git history in `History`
2. Select your commit
3. Select all the files on the right
4. Right-click on the files
5. Click on `Show in` > `Package explorer`
6. Right-click on the selected files in the Package explorer
7. Click on `Source` > `Clean Up...` ou `Format`

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to `Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Save Actions`.
2. Select Perform the selected actions on save.
3. Select `Format Source code`.
4. Select `Format edited lines`.
5. Click Ok, edit some code, save it and watch Eclipse format it automatically.

More Details are [here](http://www.eclipseonetips.com/2009/12/13/automatically-format-and-cleanup-code-every-time-you-save/), and also check the [official help](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/preferences/java/editor/ref-preferences-save-actions.htm).

[image]

Comment: Hi, This does not perform the configured clean-up just the formatter and aditional actions but it is not the same that do Source -> Clean Up  manually.

Comment: I use Source -> Cleanup Document...   At least it works and only when I want it to!!